# Laravel. Como usar requisição para realizar pesquisa em APP

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent, mariadb, laravel-6

Bom dia senhores estou iniciando meus estudos em laravel trabalhando com a versão 6 do framework, e me deparei com problema que provavelmente e um detalhe que deixei passar despercebido em meu código.

Ao tentar realizar um select no banco a partir de um requeste tenho um erro de sintaxe do mariadb.

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '.`8 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate Accept-Language: pt-BR,' at line 1 (SQL: select * from `cities` where `GET /cities?id=1 HTTP/1`.`1 Accept: text/html
```

Meu método do controller:

```
public function cities(Request $request)
{
  $cities = \App\Cities::where($request)->get(); 
  return $cities;     
}
```

Porem se eu deixar o eu alterar para esse resultado obtenho o resultado que preciso.

```
$cities = \App\Cities::where('id', '=', '1')->get();
```

Estou mandando seguinte url para o laravel http://127.0.0.1:8000/cities?id=1
e quando retorno o $request recebo a json `id   "1"`
oque preciso fazer com esse requeste antes de mandar a consulta?

obs preciso do where pois na maioria dos casos vou ter mais que resultado na busca. 
Desde já obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom dia Andrew, você esta passando o Objeto Request inteiro, também está faltando o primeiro parâmetro da clausula Where que seria a coluna de comparação no banco, no seu cado 'ID'
faça da seguinte forma e irá funcionar.

```
public function cities(Request $request)
{
  $cities = \App\Cities::where('id',$request->id)->get(); 
  return $cities;     
}
```

Existe varias formas de se obter os dados do Request segue duas.

```
$request->get('chave');
$request->input('chave');
$request->chave;
```

Comment: Desculpa minha ignorância  mais não compreendi totalmente, 'paramtro' é a coluna do banco? e esse complemento apos o requeste seria oque? '->suaVariavel_get_ou_post'
obrigado desde já.

Comment: @AndrewPalmeira dei uma editada na resposta, veja se melhorou

Comment: Compreendido! muito obrigado pela explicação, deu certinho!